# get the string between two char in php using preg_match or Symfony dom crawler

Tags: string, preg-match

I have a string like this

> Power.S04E10.You......

I want to get the `04`  and `10` in the string

note: after the s char and e char its always two digits.

in my project, I already use Symfony dom crawler

I appreciate any solution with dom crawler or preg_match

performance is an issue here because the code is placed in the loop with lots of instances.

so far I write this code that gives me the `s04e10` part from the string above. I don't know how to get the `04` and `10` separately.

```
$matches = [];
$s = 'Power.S04E10.You.Cant.Fix.This.720p.&.1080p.NF.WEB-DL.DD5.1.x264-NTb';
$t = preg_match('/s([0-9]){2}e([0-9]){2}/i', $s, $matches);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I edited the post and attached the code .

I don't know what 'captures' is .

Comment: Capturing groups `(...)` allow extracting parts of regex matches. That text is called a *capture*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$s = 'Power.S04E10.You.Cant.Fix.This.720p.&.1080p.NF.WEB-DL.DD5.1.x264-NTb';
if (preg_match('/\.s([0-9]+)e([0-9]+)\./i', $s, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1] . " - " . $matches[2]; // => 04 - 10
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/CcQFf8) and the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZNJ1f3/1).

I assume you have `SXXEYY` in between dots, if not, replace `\.` with `\b`, word boundaries.

**Pattern details**

- `\.` - a dot
- `s` - an `s` or `S`
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits (you may limit the repetitions to two if you use `([0-9]{2})` if you think it will work better)
- `e` - an `e` or `E`
- `([0-9]+)`  - `([0-9]+)` - Group 2: one or more digits (you may limit the repetitions to two if you use `([0-9]{2})` if you think it will work better)
- `\.` - a `.` char

The `$matches[1]` contains the contents of Group 1 and `$matches[2]` has the Group 2 contents.

Comment: since you explained the details. I have a question about dot char that you put before and after the pattern. does it help the performance to write more detail in the pattern?

Comment: @hamidreza I used it not for performance, but for accuracy reasons. The season and episode values seem to occur between dots. If not, replace with `\b` to make sure you match `s` and `e\d+` at word boundaries. `/\bs([0-9]+)e([0-9]+)\b/i`

Comment: right .thanks again  
it seems like there are three types of text 
`Power.S04E07.You.Lied.To.My.Face.720p.&.1080p.NF


Power S04E07 You Lied To My Face 720p & 1080p WEBRip DD5.1


Power (2014) - 04x03 - The Kind of Man You Are
`
is it possible to write preg_match with or? 
I mean is there any way to write one preg_match for above situation?

I'll add the three types to the main question if it's not readable here

Comment: @hamidreza Look, [`\bs([0-9]+)e([0-9]+)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/ZNJ1f3/2) already works for two kinds of the string and [`\b(?|s([0-9]+)e([0-9]+)|(\d+)x(\d+))\b`](https://regex101.com/r/ZNJ1f3/3) will work for all three.